# SQLAlchemy table alias with column labels

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I know about `label()`, but is it possible for SQLAlchemy to produce the following valid PostgreSQL?

```
SELECT x FROM foo() AS t(x);
```

(The `AS` is optional.)

The benefit of this syntax is that it does not depend on the name of the column returned by the set-generating function `foo()`.

For example, this allows one to write:

```
SELECT x FROM json_array_elements(json_expr) t(x);
```

instead of:

```
SELECT json_array_elements AS x FROM json_array_elements(json_expr);
```